# in silman's book, question about open files and global exchange

Tags: pawns, rooks

In a book from J.Silman, I found this position:

```
 [FEN "r1qr2k1/p2bppbp/3p2p1/1p1P4/3B1P2/1B3Q1P/PPP3P1/3RR1K1 b - - 0 17"]

 1... Re8 2. c3 h5 *
```

It deals with the rooks, white managed to semi-open the `e` column and will deploy a massive attack on it. My question is : why black does not play `e7-e5`? After `dxe6` the white pawn is sufficiently attacked by black's forces, and if there is a global exchange on `e6`, the weakening of the black's castle does not seem to be dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that after e5 and exchanges on e6 and g7 the d6-pawn is hanging ...

```
 [FEN "r1qr2k1/p2bppbp/3p2p1/1p1P4/3B1P2/1B3Q1P/PPP3P1/3RR1K1 b - - 0 17"]

 1... Re8 2. c3 e5 3.dxe6 Bxe6 4.Bxg7 Kxg7 5.Bxe6 Rxe6 6.Rxe6 fxe6 7.Rxd6
```

Comment: ok,  you're right.  I did not saw this (I must confess I do not train my calculation skills as much as I should.

Comment: Even if d6 weren't lost immediately, the general problem with solving the problem of a weak pawn on e7 by ...e7-e5 d5xe6ep and taking back with a piece is that then you will always have a new weak pawn on d6.